# Pari/GP: how do you use it?

Tags: math-software

I noticed that using Pari/GP *in console mode* is not very convenient in Windows:

[image]

- when using arrow keys, there is a long lag to see the cursor
- the key <kbd>Home</kbd> doesn't work, so it's not handy to move quickly inside a line of code.
- more generally using a notepad would be more handy

Question: **is there a way to use Pari/GP in Windows, like R's default GUI, i.e. with script on the left / console on the right**, and use something like CTRL+R to copy to console & run the current line of the script?

[image]

---

I just noticed *Sublime Text* editor has a plugin REPL that can open an interpreter inside Sublime. Sadly Pari/GP seems not supported yet.

[image]

Comment: Sad that this is on hold, I think it would be so helpful for math community to have a solution for this. I spent really a huge time searching for a solution, so I think every one starting with pari might have the same problem too. Also the tag "math software" seems adapted.

Comment: I guess programming related questions are more suitable for StackOverflow with appropriate tag, for example for Pari/GP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pari

Comment: Or maybe even better, for mathematics related software: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/